# Prevent caching of @require'd files

Tags: greasemonkey, tampermonkey, userscripts

I use `@require` to load a local JavaScript file shared by some of my GreaseMonkey scripts. When I change the file, GreaseMonkey continues to use the original version and does not load the new version. How can I disable the caching of the `@require`d file?

Comment: This question belongs to a Tampermonkey support site e.g. https://github.com/Tampermonkey/tampermonkey/issues or its forum. As for the problem, I believe TM updates external dependencies only once a day or even a week by default, there is a setting in the extension's dashboard.

Comment: I am using GreaseMonkey.  Is GreaseMonkey and TamperMonkey the same thing?

Comment: https://github.com/greasemonkey/greasemonkey/issues

Answer (score 1):

In TamperMonkey, [`file://` resources won't be cached](https://github.com/Tampermonkey/tampermonkey/issues/475#issuecomment-348637449). You should, however, enable access to file URLs at Chrome's extension management page:

[image: Allow access to file URLs option]

The are other ways to prevent caching of `@require`d files ([source](https://github.com/Tampermonkey/tampermonkey/issues/475#issuecomment-348594785)):

1. Increase the version number and save the script. All resources will be reloaded.
2. Set ["Config mode" to "Advanced"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRWmB.png) in the Setting tab. Scroll to "Externals" and set the ["Update Interval" to "Always"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/quLBP.png). "Always" means after the resource was used, so you might need to execute/load the page twice.
3. You can edit the external resources using the ["Edit" button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DGfc.png).